# AfxGetApp return NULL

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Any call on my application to AfxGetApp() returns NULL, can anyone help?

It is a .exe project converted from a .dll project, so there may be some project configurations that I am missing. I have copied configurations from another project created with the .exe wizard but is does not work. Also, I have a CWinApp that is global.

Answer (score 2):

Check your preprocessor definitions.  Remove _AFXEXT.

Comment: why is that? _AFXDLL is inherited by default on the newly created MFC .exe project.

Comment: You are right, that means "DLL version of MFC".  Ugh, I hate MFC for all these damned macros.  _AFXEXT.

Comment: this one is not present already, and also was not on the original DLL project.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem building a dll, if I copy this code (taken from another dll) AfxGetApp() returns the correct pointer:

```
CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
       // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
       _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
       nRetCode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
       // TODO: code your application's behavior here.
    }

    return nRetCode;
}
```